# What does "as a second wave, because of the miracle that is "One Man Only", it's just this" mean?

Tags: yesterday-2019

In a meeting, Stephan says about Jack:

> Stephan: We focused on the one thing that makes this man here unlike
>   anyone else in the entire world of music today. No collaborators, no
>   cowriters, no samples, no steals, hmm? no "featuring Bieber." Just the
>   simple, pure genius... of "One Man Only". And, **as a second wave,
>   because of the miracle that is "One Man Only", it's just this.**

(Stephan reveals a poster of All Music & Lyrics written by Jack only)

If I had to guess, the Stephan is emphasizing the point made that 
"One Man Only" is, in itself, something unique in the world of music today.

The "second wave" thing doesn't make sense at all in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Second wave" here indicates that this is the second iteration of marketing. The first wave was the initial marketing for Jack's music. Now, they're trying to leverage his lack of collaborators to market "One Man Only" and they have a new marketing campaign, this "second wave".

Comment: I will add as a caveat that I haven't seen the film, so this is based on plot summaries on the internet and my understanding of the English language.